# An adjective that describes written form of something without technical details?

Tags: single-word-requests

I recently posted this comment on a question in StackOverflow:

> This is my personal opinion, but I think that this is an advanced enough topic that anyone looking for a reusable solution to cache optimization for dynamic graphs would benefit more greatly by tailoring a concrete code snippet to their particular use-case than by implementing a **general explanation of the** solution from scratch. (Emphasis added)

Initially I wanted to use the word "verbal" in the bolded section to imply there was no explicit code in the answer, but I realized that "verbal" implies spoken, not written.

Comment: I'm leaning more towards the connotation that "description-only" gives, because an answer could have pseudo-code in it without getting too technical.

Comment: .., but anything that explains the objective could be considered pseudo-code.

Comment: What bolded section?

Comment: @AmI [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35091773/1541563) explains the objective without any pseudo-code. (The comment I quoted is actually below the question there).

Comment: @Lambie "general explanation of the"

Comment: Something like *narrative* or *exposition*, I suppose.

Comment: _Narrative_ is very close to what I'm looking for. Post that as an answer and I'll definitely upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...than by implementing the **overview** of the solution from scratch.

This assumes that someone posted a high-level explanation of an existing algorithm or solution, and you are suggesting an actual implementation?

edit: misread question at first.

Comment: Yes I am suggesting exactly that. Great word!

Answer (score 1):

You may say that "the concrete code snippet **speaks better than a thousand words**"

Comment: That's not at all what I'm asking. Can you please suggest a single word that can replace the phrase "general explanation of the" in my original quote?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - Consider **presentation** or **rundown/synopsis** (for an overview).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you want to use the word *solution*. If you are willing to let go of that word, you can use ***design document*** or ***specification*** to make your point.

> ... than by implementing a *specification* from scratch.

In terms of a single word replacement for the phrase *general explanation of the* that gives a more written connotation than the word *verbal*, I have to say that *verbal* seems a very good choice to me. Alternatives that came to my mind were ***narrative*** or ***exposited*** (the latter has a less spoken connotation than the former).

> ... than by implementing an *exposited* solution from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

This is my personal opinion, but I think this topic is advanced enough **so** anyone looking for a solution to cache optimization for dynamic graphs would **benefit more from** tailoring a code snippet to their particular use-case ** than** from creating a generic solution from scratch. //If you create a snippet of code, it is "concrete". No need to say it.

Comment: Okay, I agree with the comment about "concrete", but I feel that the part I focused on still needs a descriptor to really explain what I meant by a non-code solution.

Comment: solutions exist, if you create a new solution, in the software world, you are creating a new version of the solution. The structure of your sentence was not right. New solution from scratch says it all.

Comment: a generic solution